# Infer return type from generic types

Tags: typescript

I want to infer a type in a specific situation to either get a `Box<T>` or a `T`, based on an input parameter, but I end up with `Box<unknown>` and unknown instead.
I think it is because of my usage of `W extends Wrap<T>`, but I don't know how to express this better.

See this code example, hover over `boxResult` and `noBoxResult` to see the inferred types are not ideal for me:

```js
// Type definitions

interface ComplicatedDataContainer<T> {
    // contains many Ts in some complicated fashion
}
interface WrapA<T> {
    v: ComplicatedDataContainer<T>,
    p: "Box"
}
interface WrapB<T> {
    v: ComplicatedDataContainer<T>,
    p: "NoBox"
}
type Wrap<T> = WrapA<T> | WrapB<T>;

type Box<T> = {
    t: T
}

type SelectThing = <T, W extends Wrap<T>>(id: string, w: W) => W extends {p: "Box"} ? Box<T> : T

// Usage example

const wBox: WrapA<string> = {
    v: "",
    p: "Box"
}

const wNoBox: WrapB<string> = {
    v: "",
    p: "NoBox"
}

const selector: SelectThing = (id: string, w: Wrap<any>) => {throw new Error()}; // dont care about runtime behavior here, real impls are way more complicated

// I want the type of this to be Box<string>, but it is Box<unknown>
const boxResult = selector("", wBox);
// I want the type of this to be string, but it is unknown
const noBoxResult = selector("", wNoBox);
```

You can run this example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-OJdJApNjFiEsHYKLhUaA0gmAKIUOMUKGY5y7ZRgBDqVTUCjwagAI1wAFcBRQK8JUMx4KXYHZqOE8BRQHZKLA-sXqGxQPX2Foi-BUdR9MxnWY2pYEghGWAAJKC3QCmPwW6gXDIUAx1BaJ2gJu04pigOSv6lquDgUH0-iWsAa3Q8fQUnV+E15eKACVYAQFZsAKyz2u6ToZvKaKTJi+wqCu47CHuXZ7rM267vuh64Me8AGp8V43tgg5aM+r6ok4tqJhMJT-oBwHemBjrOlCUFatRxSwUAA).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WoJ3em) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please explain what's missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there's no inference site for `T` so it defaults to `unknown`. Actually you don't need a separate type parameter `T` here, since it can be derived from the type parameter `W`. The `Unwrap` type below does this derivation.

```
type Unwrap<W extends Wrap<any>> = W extends Wrap<infer T> ? T : never

type SelectThing =
    <W extends Wrap<any>>(id: string, w: W) => W extends {p: "Box"} ? Box<Unwrap<W>> : Unwrap<W>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2qAuqD26BnAKCIy1gCdkBDAY3gGFcBbaAG1VuvIQBFvqTdFmoZKAHnAA+UAG8ioRaGS5cALggBuBUoBG1ChvDaAvqWGUa9UAHUK1aAEFJM+UtAA3DU1YcuPfhEhETEKFwAaHUVoDQAiACFcAA9YojMySzp4Owd4lzkoz28Wdk5uWD4BYNF0CWlI9xjQWIA5XESUtKIsGGz7aHyAXlt+52lQAB8R3Jdtbt7QDqGC9ywjLvm4UABVdAB3fvEbUFgk8nQEAmmB6nRIKRlh49Pzy+vxDGRKCBkAfghQBpah5KCQelsAMqwNiwWhYcAACwwAHNQMMjiczrALlccjc7g8ABSoBAaAhYCgo8KgPYaGwASjRMmeWJxciaCWSsRMoH+S12BwcRwegJ2+0ONikJBAOwI1GR8FO1F8sBItHw5JpHTpo3E5Mp6GRjxWSi8chU6masWp+kMVpMDSUHI6qTMRHVhCwNLa2uueX1KONblNGlkFri1tAtojDsKHJ9XI2Hs1BGhsKwuDtUJhcMRKLRoGJpNAAcN1Np71u90Zg1cWARFFwe1AtWbAFEKI2KIT6SZNKAZQh8F6uBR4NRdLgAK5eihT4SoZjwXSwBHUDx4CigBGUWDUsfUNigRfsK4GeB7aiQUDMTPwdW+Mo8aVgACSNNuXvr8HB8FwyFAetUCuDMo3gJZSyNG0Z2PL1gMWZJxHnABrdAm3QKVky9SckgAJVgAgpzYL1hlTHMM27WJIz2Dp6W0GV30vYRAJ3QCFn-Fj4NAlcSwpKkoxg7BjyuFC0L2dB3Q1L00I6fDCOIgsyPTTNCSo8sEySOigA)

Note that I had to fill in `ComplicatedDataContainer` in the example so that it depends on `T` in some way, to avoid unintended [structural equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).

Comment: Oh heh I just did [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoJ3em) which looks exactly the same as yours.  +1 for you! :runs away:

Comment: This just works

Comment: So I think this is a great solution and it seems to work fine inside a single project, but the real world usecase for me is a package. Once I publish that package and use it in another project as npm dependency suddenly the type inferences does not work anymore, it's back to unknown. Any simple reasons why that would happen?

Comment: No idea; you'd have to post a new question (with some code that reproduces the issue).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will try to figure out a way to make a small reproduction.