# Return inferred generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to return the inferred type from a function on a class, but the return type is of the extended generic type, not the actual result of the function.  I want to instead return the inferred type of the function.

I tried a few things surrounding wrapping and unwrapping, but was unable to get those to work.

**Problem**: `newDocumentSet` is of type `IDocumentSet<DocumentTypes, IContact, never>`, not the type returned in the create functions extend parameter

**Notes**: I would like the create function to return the extended instance, not the interface of `IDocumentSet`. It seems like this bit (create<TExtension extends IDocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity, TExtraExclusions>>) is screwing it up, I am just not sure how to enforce a return type that extends `IDocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity, TExtraExclusions>` yet returns the extended type not `IDocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity, TExtraExclusions>`.

**Goal**: I want to create the ability to return the extended class from the create function, not the interface.

Example is below and here in [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUCUHkCEBkCiBZAXAWAFAlAOwKYDuAIgPYDGArgLb64AuAyvvaAJYDOopAZqPQE8ADvlABJMlVoNm9ADySadegBVh+DgBpxAYVIMAhuXraCAN3wAnAHynSregAtRgkaA4jybHm3wATdlx+Z1ByS3wDelF8AA8o3AChA0sDWijLLCwcADloFURGDGwwMVBCUkoAGwDKtgBrUTCIqP5SUHD6Sksgp2i4uj9-QI56A1xyfDsHELYGKx4jUV5xRWkmFiyS0DrcUkJgzlAAIzZWAAomyPw5fP7cDjZ9UFj4vy4JCiUZFhvV5TURNp8gxTgIgYg4ikIeRKpQHvoONZrABKdhcDhNQizADm7FYlCE2lKqVAACs4axdqwOF1RJtQI49q1nrgeKRLBNQAZ2iwuj11MFIs87m8Vp81rJfuL-upwSDBODIQZobD4fdrKABCweZ1ulxesLXkNXPh6VSxVJlJKVH8GADJqBgfRQYr6FCYjC4Y91ZliqAAFSB0AAaXw+CEgVA1FmAQ4pFooVIgy5XCOYaC8dOUQC9Da1AMDQOXFiqSElVEHHzlXLlgDgd9OAA4tAAILwIo4UqEMYONqXFoGgwnWqCZkdPnBPpGgIwgwcLg8SzxyehcJXUA8SjjZ36X2xITs1izdILTkfS3feiwOfXG3Su0Cl4DdFunEagDevtA39A2O1ttUdQzmRVBHQA+0AG4vx-fBqCEQRgNA8Al2jDhrjMUg2D8awoMwABfX1j3mRYLS+dZ5DvC9ALcJ8EhfSwcTlZ1R1o0UJCOSB8HIdk-ClKj7VsR0ITdZUPVVb1ixFLgzgaARlidUFUQAXjwfALBsQ1n1IiUWGvNC+LIgTQE-TAf0CNlEOOUhSHLMYsAIzAsCIyxT1EdjOO4yxeMowz1A1Vj3mII4Wz8PxTm9DyeIMtYjJMsy1z8fRKgEUAAH0sNAkYGNwbFcPiiJEtwZK0vCMxMtfHLcIcpy5hckj2JCsKd1wSKvJuD8sHygxCuK8D1FAlQqr3GID0sVhZ3nUAAOtPqaKk9wKuxJjQU0uiVg4riop8mK-Ndd1PTVSTXmk2T5MQeUBGU1T1I1Ng4PLNZAvvcjoplQEhIuvbRIOiSOsc0yfyEBizHXVLEv4-qwOeyDoO-P9WFm-BgOMnUJycTgADoweh9QINAaqAe-bj7jdShjHZM5wd8kQBsR1E4rMn90Y4LGqZ2twVLZt78Dyn8CbM2YLPpzrGe-cdun4SxKB5kXv35n85wEcZnjghDhf+syHIJiauFgSg2GqKxXofObjoW7Klo+5iUoC9bWu8xHBNuESVS9BFVtFGT8DkvgFMEK7zCsP7ZdAIG2BBlpsYhmmoejmWNZ-YmsrJ3NLEpnGY+27n1dF79mdZjPRE5wvebl2HV2aW9hLoNUPaeqiZsL5aFSEpVXcOpEzlY0CzjEEmxgmUCTWWaafizk2HT9sFW5dsS3fVbQuYn2nC+UjVnZr71QBU-YlI1M59jnLlcEulMZ83-R1ZDsyk9YcIaUqVgVNYs5R4oxHm+n539vEhFBPzqO1N8DIlwtfH84sgj3yqPQUu+N7J7lwDQKahcuAM2-HoQwxguAqQAEQYNGFgnB8D-rOVcrofQBDWC23cptNqiNETGRDj4SwIxsipHwOVC2sDKhznoGw2gnCcSwO6n4e+HBBGVRDkIRkBAJG5WIVgW+xx9aG1rCpAg+w9YG0GJYBQKCiT4KMPQawr8UEY0MVgkBvolEaLftvZR2irAY37EjXu-dxgOiXtRYB28-r5V1EEDRoQeGTWoe4zkaDGa3yluTNOOdc5mRpCINOXj7TIjAWXBOosogjGRpEhJEDQA4LjAmEGsJ8A4NgZrEOWsQFAA) fiddle

[Shorter Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIg9gY0qALgFQJ4AdgGcoDeAsAFBTlQDCcIKAhgivgLxQBE1tDTbpAvqVIBLWsABOAMwbAoASU71GhQSQElhoydLnwkEVAGVgKADxpdyWphxRgADxSgAJvlwoxIgOYAaKGgCitEIoGLYOzvgEfAB8ymQUuHD6AGJgIIxCNAAUToiW6NjAAFx+FvpWhQCUJQFBIQDc-CoIADZ0uPhlhsZmXRU29o4gLlBuHiA+foEowaGDEYQxUEIQWC3A5Uw6eZtGpuY7qNbAvrUzIbHE8eSJKWkZ2bl6R4U1fQU4lXEUP1BixmAxCBFlB2lM6hhGtcoGo1KRWu18AAhMBCFpOcS9Q79GTzYaudxeU7TWZhIYjKKXFQ-BD-OiOMz+cIgXCZYF4kayd57LHPHHEiHRaJZDklLKyFn0dLFKAhHBwCSwbEoHkHPkfE7g84YaJfZixALM1k0KCsADuptiWQtYLoIAwXzBhqGxpAXyuvwo-xQgPZzKcWW5xkqUJ+cNUzRobigACNUejxKaoCBgBaUWiMWITO9jrhfPIaIoUMKQ5HJVAIBgAHKpvZJuMZ8QAOlpwHpwCy4sldoQwD1VOh3t9ydTUARHTJCwlbh7Mg9ntGSWANbNqXSM2y7tIC9+Q6B7FuMgAbnQWmBgGxQwu1GH+KX1CQAPSPivV2vGZb4BWywrbdU8nNCjzOQFG4WI7ScZM4BQV9QRAGgMAgOAwHwcd8BQAALelPz+AEgWAJxSCAA)

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713746/infer-return-type-from-generic-types) post about wrapping and unwrapping, but was unable to get it to work for my needs

*This example is from a larger code base, code surrounding `TExtraExclusions` has been omitted to keep this example smaller, yet the generics remain.*

```js
export interface IDocumentSetBase<TDocumentType extends string> {

    get DocumentType(): TDocumentType;

    empty(): Promise<void>;
}

interface IDocumentSet<TDocumentType extends string, TEntity extends IDbRecord<TDocumentType>, TExtraExclusions extends (keyof TEntity) = never> extends IDocumentSetBase<TDocumentType> {
    info(): boolean
}

interface IDbRecord<TDocumentType> extends IDbAdditionRecord<TDocumentType> {
    readonly _id: string;
    readonly _rev: string;
}

interface IDbAdditionRecord<T> {
    readonly DocumentType: T;
}

export class DocumentSet<TDocumentType extends string, TEntity extends IDbRecord<TDocumentType>, TExtraExclusions extends (keyof TEntity) = never> implements IDocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity, TExtraExclusions> {

    private _documentType: TDocumentType;

    get DocumentType() { return this._documentType; }

    constructor(documentType: TDocumentType) {
        this._documentType = documentType;
    }

    info() {
        return true;
    }

    async empty() {

    }
}

class Builder<TDocumentType extends string, TEntity extends IDbRecord<TDocumentType>, TExtraExclusions extends (keyof TEntity) = never> {

    private _documentType: TDocumentType;

    constructor(documentType: TDocumentType) {
        this._documentType = documentType;
    }

    create<TExtension extends IDocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity, TExtraExclusions>>(extend: (Instance: typeof DocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity, TExtraExclusions>, documentType: TDocumentType) => TExtension = w => (w as any) as TExtension) {

        const result = extend(DocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity, TExtraExclusions>, this._documentType);

        return result;
    }
}

enum DocumentTypes {
    Contacts = "Contacts"
}

interface IContact extends IDbRecord<DocumentTypes> {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    address: string;
    phone: string;
}

const builder = new Builder<DocumentTypes, IContact>(DocumentTypes.Contacts);

const newDocumentSet = builder.create((Instance, documentType) => {
    return new class extends Instance {
        constructor() {
            super(documentType)
        }

        test() {
            return "some value";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If possible, it would be helpful if you could shrink your examble - which is working, no errors - so that it's more clear where the "problem" is.

Comment: Sounds good, let me take a few minutes to shrink it and see if it helps @MikeS.

Comment: Shorter example added above @MikeS.

Comment: You shorter code might be too short if your generic interfaces have no structural dependence on the type parameters.  Something like `interface Foo<T> { x: string }` has no dependence on `T`, and so `Foo<string>` and `Foo<number>` are the same, and you can't necessarily infer `string` from `Foo<string>`.  Please give your interfaces a structural dependence on the type parameters to avoid [weird](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--) things happening. (This is probably not your issue, but I don't want it to be a distraction)

Comment: Shorter example has been updated @jcalz.  The interface is now implemented

Comment: I would say that your [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) is interacting badly with inference.  *Might* be a TS bug, but I don't know, since instantiation expressions are so new.  I'd suggest not using them, and just writing out the type directly, like [this playground link example](https://tsplay.dev/WGVjMm) shows.  If that works for you I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing about your question?

Comment: That looks like the answer @jcalz.  If you want to write out the answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shorter example, you are using the [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) `typeof DocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity>` to refer to the type of a [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#generic-classes) constructor whose generic type parameters have been specified with the arguments `TDocumentType, TEntity`.  That is, a type essentially the same as `new() => DocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity>` (using a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures)).

If you replace the instantiation expression with the equivalent type:

```
create<TExtension extends IDocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity>>(
    extend: (Instance: new () => DocumentSet<TDocumentType, TEntity>
    ) => TExtension = w => (w as any) as TExtension) {
    return extend(DocumentSet);
}
```

Then you get the expected inference when you call `extend()`:

```
myNewSet.someNewFunction(); // okay
```

---

I'm not sure *why* it doesn't work the way you wrote it.  Instantiation expressions are new (they were introduced in TypeScript 4.7 which is the latest release version), so I can't tell if this inference failure is a language bug, or a design limitation, or the intentional behavior.  If it matters, someone might want to open [an issue in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) asking about it.  If that happens and we get an answer, we can update this post.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIg9gY0qALgFQJ4AdgGcoDeAsAFBTlQDCcIKAhgivgLxQBE1tDTbpAvqVIBLWsABOAMwbAoASU71GhQSQElhoydLnwkEVAGVgKADxpdyWphxRgADxSgAJvlwoxIgOYAaKGgCitEIoGLYOzvgEfAB8ymQUuHD6AGJgIIxCNAAUToiW6NjAAFx+FvpWhQCUJQFBIQDc-CoIADZ0uPhlhsZmXRU29o4gLlBuHiA+foEowaGDEYQxUEIQWC3A5Uw6eZtGpuY7qNbAvrUzIbHE8eSJKWkZ2bl6R4U1fQU4lXEUP1BixmAxCBFlB2lM6hhGtcoGo1KRWu18AAhMBCFpOcS9Q79GTzYaudxeU7TWZhIYjKKXFQ-BD-OiOMz+cIgXCZYF4kayd57LHPHHEiHRaJZUi-CgckpZWQs+jpYpQEDAADuUCyX2YsW5PQOfI+J3B5ww0VFYqg6tiAWZrJoUFYKo1qpVYLoIAwXzBlqG1pAXyupr+AKBZOcWS1KEqUJ+cNUzRobigACNUejxLaFcqoCi0RixCZ3sdcL55DRFChhRHYzKoBAMAA5ZV7NNJ7PiAB0tOA9OAWSlMpdCGA5u+FH+KEBwMVKoRHWD+Lkfblw7Ft2A9aVqXSM2yvpN-vIo-H7BXUAAbnQWmBgGxI6a1FH+BX1CQa2u9q2V2uNw8QGr6lAAPT-lAcAANZ0BgQA)